# Algorithm to find combinations of sets of numbers that add up to equal or greater than X

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

So the problem I'm trying to solve is that I would like to find the possible combinations of numbers in the sets that I have that add up to 400

I have 6 numbers in set 1 that can be any of the following: [0, 6, 8, 12, 16, 30]
and another 6 numbers in set 2 that can be any of the following: [0, 16, 20, 25, 32, 40, 50]

I recognize that since all I'm concerned about is the sum, order should not matter, but I'm not sure how I'd actually approach the set up. Would it make sense to approach it changing 1 number at a time, decreasing in value for each iteration, then once I hit a total under 400 breaking that run and moving to the next number? For example:
If I started with [30,30,30,30,30,30][50,50,50,50,50,50] decreasing in the last index, once I hit [30,30,30,30,30,30][50,50,50,32,20,16] the rest of the iterations focused on that 11th column (there's only one more and that's when its equal to 16) could be ignored because they only decrease.
Or is there a more logical method to approach this with?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, although I would be glad to answer it. This Maybe belongs in data science or game theory or something, but not python, even if you are trying to do it in python, because you are simply asking if there is a better logical (or mathematical) METHOD to approach this question; not how to do X, Y, or Z approach in python, which you have tried but are running into an error.

Comment: This is a so-called zero-one assignment problem, which is a subset of integer programming, which is a subset of constrained optimization. A web search for those terms will find some resources. Essentially you want to find a1, a2, ... a6, and b1, b2, ... b6, such that each ak and each bk is either 0 or 1, with a1 m1 + a2 m2 + ... + a6 m6 + b1 n1 + b2 n2 + ... + b6 n6 = 400. GLPK is a package which can solve such problems. If you want to create your own implementation, there are probably relatively simple algorithms. You can start with brute force (try all 2^12 combinations).

Comment: @RobertDodier's method O(n) is likely slightly faster (computationally) than mine O(2n) or O(3n) but both of those end up being simplified to O(n) anyway, but if you were doing it by hand I would argue logically the way I suggested is "easier" for a human to do than brute-forcing it.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate the help! I'll give these methods a try

Answer (score 0):

You can order both sets, set a loop for each num in the first set to be summed to every num in the second but you can stop once your sum fails to be over 400.

Something like

```
numbers_whose_sums_are_bigger_than_the_number_in_question = []
for x in ordered_set_a: 
    sum = 401
    while sum > 400:
        for y in ordered_set_b:
            sum = x + y
            if sum > 400:
                numbers_whose_sums_are_bigger_than_the_number_in_question.append([x,y])
print(numbers_whose_sums_are_bigger_than_the_number_in_question)
```